# Current line has two long thin lines arround it

Tags: visual-studio-code

The current line (16) in my VS Code has two lines that I want to remove:

[image]

How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode has a setting called "Render Line Highlight", with one of the options being "none".

To access it, navigate to `File > Preferences > Settings` and search for "Render Line Highlight"

[image: Settings screenshot showing the line options]

Answer (score 0):

The lines are a feature of the theme that your copy of VS Codes is set to. Choose a theme that dosen't highlight the current line in this way.

On my MacBook, I can press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and, in the resulting text field, enter `>color theme` (yes, including the `>` character) to see a selectable list of other themes.

Or, I can go to the menu `Code` > `Settings` > `Settings` and search for `color theme`, which reveals a drop-down of different themes.